# How Can I Click This Link Using Watir?

Tags: hyperlink, watir

I want to navigate a site using `watir`.  I can't find nor focus on an element to click on it.  It's the **Next** link on top right of this url:

[Companies](https://healthspace.com/Clients/Ontario/KFLA/Web.nsf/module_facilities.xsp?module=Food)

How can I test that the link exists and can focus on it to click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link HTML is:

```
<a id="view:_id1:_id258:pager6__Next__lnk" href="#" title="Go to next page:">Next</a>
```

The identifiable attributes seem to be the id (being careful of the auto-generated portions) or the title. The link could be located by either:

```
browser.link(title: 'Go to next page:')  # using title
browser.link(id: /Next__lnk/)            # using partial id
```

You can check if the link is available by checking if it is present:

```
browser.link(title: 'Go to next page:').present?
```

You can click with:

```
browser.link(title: 'Go to next page:').click
```

Comment: Oh the `partial id` is interesting.  I was looking for a wildcard solution for that.  `puts a.link(title: 'go to next page:').exists?` doesn't work.
`puts a.link(id: /Next__lnk/).exists?` works. Thank you!

Comment: `puts a.link(title: 'go to next page:').exists?` won't work because the "Go" needs to be capitalized. The string locator is case-sensitive.

Comment: Not clickable:  `0   chromedriver                        0x0000000100e1f0fc chromedriver + 4223228: element click intercepted: Element <a id="view:_id1:_id258:pager6__...__lnk" href="#" title="Go to next page:">Next</a> is not clickable at point (756, 8). Other element would receive the click: <div style="padding-right:10.0px" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)`  This shows as __existing__ but I can't click i for some reason.

Comment: That's not the one I'm using.  `  a.link(id: /Next__lnk/).click if a.link(id: /Next__lnk/).exists?`

Comment: Same error on that `selector`: `0   chromedriver                        0x00000001026930fc chromedriver + 4223228: element click intercepted: Element <a id="view:_id1:_id258:pager6__...__lnk" href="#" title="Go to next page:">Next</a> is not clickable at point (756, 8). Other element would receive the click: <div style="padding-right:10.0px" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div> (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)`

Comment: Seems like the link is under the header bar. Try scrolling it to the center before clicking it - `a.link(id: /Next__lnk/).tap { |e| e.scroll.to(:center) }.click`

Comment: Brilliant.  I didn't consider the page had scrolled it out of `visibility`.

Comment: The click doesn't work: `a.link(title: 'Go to next page:').click`  Not sure why.  No feedback.

Comment: How are you evaluating that the click doesn't work? It's a slow ajax request. You need to make sure you have an explicit wait for the table to update.

Comment: I've not seen it progress.  Anyway that project is closed.  Had to move on.